# Eloquent group an array by carbon date week & count

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I have an array of 91 items I wish to group the array items by the carbon date by week.

Example data -

```
 Collection {#240 ▼
  #items: array:91 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▶]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "date" => Carbon {#278 ▼
        +"date": "2017-06-24 15:02:04.000000"
        +"timezone_type": 3
        +"timezone": "UTC"
      }
      "visitors" => 11
    ]
```

This is my current attempt -

```
$dataViewQuarterly = $analytics->fetchSessions(Period::days(91))->take(91)->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->date)->format('w');
});
```

It's currently throwing a `Trying to get property of non-object` on this line -

```
return Carbon::parse($date->date)->format('w');
```

Is this the best way to go about it. Should I be building a new array with this data.

Comment: which line gives you the non object error?

Comment: `Period::days(91)` what it will give ? Is it a scoped query ?

Comment: That won't work. You're basically telling MySQL to group the results by an integer.

Comment: Updated question, period 91 returns 91 results into the array, that's just a call to the number of days worth of results I want.

Comment: You can add laravel's **whoops error page** if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `startOfWeek` Carbon method

```
$dataViewQuarterly = $analytics->fetchSessions(Period::days(91))->take(91)->groupBy(function($date) {
 return Carbon::parse($date->date)->startOfWeek();
});
```

Comment: That still throws the ```Trying to get property of non-object``` error

Comment: You have some objects in you collection with the `date` property non set

Comment: No the date is always set if I change the results period from 91 to 1 so that I only return a single result it still throws the same error, I can then check the date is set on a single result.

Comment: You may need to call `toDateString` after `startOfWeek`.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a non-carbon & non-eloquent way of doing things but it does work. As the data is different every day it's a rolling 6 months so the fact I chunk the array every 7 items don't actually impact the data.

```
    $dataFetchQuarterly = $analytics->fetchSessions(Period::days(91))->take(91)->toArray();
    $weeks = array_chunk($dataFetchQuarterly, 7);

    $dataViewQuarterly = array();

    foreach($weeks as $index=>$sub_array) {
        $counter = 0;

        foreach($sub_array as $donut) {
            $counter += $donut['visitors'];
        }

        $dataViewQuarterly[$index] = $counter;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this I will help however I need to look into your `$date` I am not sure what you have in it??

```
$dataViewQuarterly = $analytics->fetchSessions(Period::days(91))->take(91)->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('w');
});
```